# Expresión regular para encontrar comentarios de Python

Tags: python, regex

busco un poco de ayuda para buscar una expresión regular que identifique los comentarios en Python.

```
Serian como estos:
#Esto es un comentario en Python
"""Este es un comentario multilínea.
Podemos escribir tantas líneas queramos a modo de documentación."""
'''También podemos hacer comentarios multilíneas con comillas 
simples.'''
```

Estoy tratando de hacer un archivo .flex, pero los comentarios multilinea me dan problema y no los identifica, esto es lo que he hecho.

```
//COMPONENTES LEXICOS
Espacio = " "
Palabra = {Letra} {Letra}*
Letra = [A-Za-z]
texto =[A-ZÑ][A-ZÑa-zñ0-9]*
//COMENTARIOS
comentariosimples = ("#"{Palabra}*{Palabra}*{Palabra}*{Palabra}* 
{Palabra}*)
comentariosmultilinea1 = ("'''"{Espacio}*{Palabra}*{Espacio}*"'''")
comentariosmultilinea2 = (" \"\"\"\" "{Espacio}*{Palabra}*{Espacio}*" 
\"\"\"\" ")
```

Comment: Qué has intentado? realmente la sintáxis en regex requerida en esta pregunta no es compleja. Tal vez al primer intento te de resultados. te recomiendo [click aquí](https://regex101.com/) para hacer pruebas.

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacer un archivo .flex y trato de encontrar una expresión regular en particular, editare la publicación.

Comment: Intenta usar el flag DOTALL en la expresión regular, así el comodín punto también coincidirá con newline.

Comment: comencemos por el lado en que la única forma de declarar un comentario es con `#`, luego la sintaxis de las comillas `""" """` se llama *doc-strings* (que no es igual que un comentario).

Comment: Entonces como identificaría los _doc-strings_ ?

Comment: ¿No sirve recorrer la entrada y usar simples operaciones de string?

Answer (score -1):

### Detectar: Comentarios simples

1. Capturar el primer caracter `#`
2. Capturar cualquier caracter `.`
3. repetir el paso 2 varias veces.

Regex: `#.+`

###### Explicación:

Capturar cualquier caracter después de un `#`

### Detectar: doc-string

1. Capturar literalmente `\"`
2. Capturar tres veces el paso 1 `\"{3}`
3. Capturar cualquier caracter varias veces `.+`
4. Capturar nueva linea `\n`
5. Capturar varias lineas de texto `(.+\n.+)*`

Regex: `\"{3}(.+\n.+)*\"{3}`

###### Explicación:

Capturar comillas triples incluyendo texto multilinea hasta encontrar nuevamente comillas triples

Para unir ambas en una misma "petición" puedes emplear `regex1|regex2`

*Con bandera en **global**, se asume que el string tiene saltos de línea*

Siempre me guío de estos recursos para generar sintáxis en regex, por lo que los recomiendo:

- [w3schools: Python RegEx](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)
- [Documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#)
- [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Fallaría con un doc string que no tenga saltos de línea o si hay más de 1 doc string en el texto